# Using phoenix dynamic columns in a spark dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-phoenix, apache-spark-sql

Phoenix has the capability of added dynamic columns after an initial schema has been chosen for a table.  You can add columns dynamically during upserts.  My question is how do I use these columns effectively, particularly in spark dataframes?  I understand upon connection of the spark dataframe phoenix has the schema and I know the dynamic columns are not in the schema.  So is this possible?